# start all services which are not running and start with the same name

Tags: batch-file

I have 5 services that start with the name "test".
I need a batch file that will check each one of them and start it in case the service is down.

I have such a script which is working in case of 1 service but ?I dont know how to change it to multiple services:

```
net start | find "test gap" > nul 2>&1 
if not .%errorlevel%.==.0. goto startservice 
goto skip


:startservice 
net start "Cem Execution Service" 
echo service restarts @ %date% %time% >> C:\checklog.txt 

:skip
pause
```

Comment: Can't you just repeat the code for each service with the correct service name?

Answer (score 0):

You could put `net start` into a for loop.

Example:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('net start ^| find /i "Test"') do net start "%%a"
```

Replace `%%a` with `%a` if not running from a batch file.

**Edit:** If you also want to log it with a time stamp as well it gets a little more tricky as we need `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('net start ^| find /i "Test"') do net start "%%a" && echo service restarts @ !date! !time! >> C:\checklog.txt
```

Note: The `&&` means it will only execute if net start was successful.  So if the service failed to start, or was already started it won't log.